# Is it possible to hook to WinLogon proc when logon to window?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, winlogon

I need to develop a dll which will be called whenever somebody logon to window.
This dll will hook to the WinLogon proc and do something, the WinLogon process will be suspended until the dll done their work.

I tried to take around stackoverflow as well as msdn but I can't find the relevant article.

Is there anyone here can give me some related article or suggestion?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Sounds like some kind of a virus.

Comment: hi @EugeneSh, I want to do our roaming profile solution... so I need to receive the event and move registry dat files before profile load it.

Comment: Is there still the option of creating your own gina dll? Edit: I think not but the documentation is confusing: ***GINA DLLs are ignored in Windows Vista.*** Why then does it have a 2018 date? [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/building-and-testing-a-gina-dll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/building-and-testing-a-gina-dll)

Comment: If a custom GINA dll does no longer work in the currently supported versions of windows I don't have an idea.

Comment: hi @drescherjm, thank you, if I can't use dll, is there any further way ?

Comment: Look for events the Windows system fires at startup and/or logon. Then you might try to write an autostarted application that reacts on these events, or one of them. Who said that life as a developer is easy? It takes a lot of reading, experimenting, failing, and all over again.

Comment: Try creating a [Winlogon Notification Package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/winlogon-notification-packages): "*Winlogon notification packages are DLLs that receive and handle events generated by Winlogon. You can implement such a notification package to monitor and respond to Winlogon events. This is useful for applications that need to perform additional processing during logon or logoff, or maintain state information that must be updated when Winlogon events occur.*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows 2000，Windows XP and Windows Server 2003, you could use [Winlogon Notification Package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/winlogon-notification-packages). But in Windows Vista and later, Winlogon notification packages are no longer supported, see [Winlogon Notification Packages Removed: Impact on Windows Vista Planning and Deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-vista/cc721961(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

You can use the alternative solutions listed in the document to hook the logon event. It should be noted that Service Control Manager (SCM) Notifications and System Event Notification Service (SENS) are usually asynchronous, and Group Policy Scripts are also asynchronous by default to improve system boot and login performance.

However, there is a Group Policy option to have scripts executed synchronously(`Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Scripts\Run startup scripts synchronously`).
**Please note that this is not a recommended configuration and should only be used if no other methods are available. You must also extensively test the script to ensure that it does not cause any system performance problems.**